# Finding the remainder of $5^{5} \div 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So this seems like a simple question,
Using a calculator, I found that $5^{5} \mod 7 = 3$.

But I had problems when trying to solve this using basic algebra,
Here is what I've done :
$5^3 = 125 ≡ 6[7] ≡ -1 [7]$. 
Then I wrote: 
1 ) $5^5 = (5^3)^2 ≡ (-1)^2 [7] ≡ 1 [7].$
This is false, but I can't figure out why...

Also,
2 ) $5^5 = 5^3 * 5^2 ≡ -1 * 4[7] ≡ 3 [7]$ works.

I don't understand why expression 1) doesn't work but 2) does.

Comment: $(5^3)^2=5^6\neq5^5$

Comment: Indices are multiplied when you add an exponent to an exponential expression. As mentioned in the comments, $5^3 × 5^2 = 5^5$. $(5^3)^2 = 5^{2×3} = 5^6$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, choose the tags carefully. This is not Euclidean Geometry nor Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple problem, simple mistake :

$(5^3)^2=5^6\neq5^5$

I've still got lots to learn :)

Thanks Learning Mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answer has dissected the OP's mistake:

Alternative approach:

Mod 7:

$5^5 \equiv (-2)^5 \equiv (-32) \equiv 3.$